# How to enable or disable textbox and button from listbox selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying use the validation feature to enable or disable a textbox and button when a listbox value is selected. Please see example code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function exampleListBox(){
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Example').setHeight(100).setWidth(250);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(5, 3);
var listbox = app.createListBox().setId('lb1').addItem('None').addItem('Item1').addItem('Item2').addItem('Item3').addItem('Item4');
var textbox = app.createTextBox().setId('tb1').setText('None').setEnabled(false);
var pressme = app.createButton('press me').setId('btn1').setEnabled(false);

var chandler1 = app.createClientHandler()
.validateMatches(listbox, 'Item1, Item3')
.forTargets(textbox).setEnabled(true)
.validateNotMatches(listbox, 'None, Item1, Item4')
.forTargets(textbox).setEnabled(false);

grid.setWidget(0, 0, listbox)
.setWidget(0, 1, textbox).addClickHandler(chandler1)
.setWidget(1, 1, pressme);

app.add(grid)
app.add(panel) 
ss.show(app);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the client handler to the list or to the whole grid instead. Also, you can't combine both function in a single client handlere, I would create one for each desired effect (enable and disable)

and last, the argument in the `validateMatches` method is a regular expression, not a simple string concatenation so if you want the condition to be true on "Item1" or "Item3" you should use a regex that validates on these 2 values.
Here is an example code that does not work exactly how it should but shows the begining of the right way ...

```
function exampleListBox(){
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Example').setHeight(100).setWidth(250);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(5, 3);
var listbox = app.createListBox().setId('lb1').addItem('None').addItem('Item1').addItem('Item2').addItem('Item3').addItem('Item4');
var textbox = app.createTextBox().setId('tb1').setText('None').setEnabled(false);
var pressme = app.createButton('press me').setId('btn1').setEnabled(false);

var chandler1 = app.createClientHandler()
.validateMatches(listbox, 'Item1')
.forTargets(textbox,pressme).setEnabled(true);
var chandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
.validateMatches(listbox, 'None')
.forTargets(textbox,pressme).setEnabled(false);

  grid.addClickHandler(chandler1).addClickHandler(chandler2)
grid.setWidget(0, 0, listbox)
.setWidget(0, 1, textbox)
.setWidget(1, 1, pressme);

app.add(grid)
app.add(panel) 
ss.show(app);
}
```

I'm not good enough at regex to implement the multi-condition in the validateMatches but I'm sure you will find it somewhere. If not, ask on SO with JavaScript Tag, these guys are just amazing ^^

Comment: Hi Serge! Thank you once again. I will play with this step up and see where it takes me. I will try the regex out as well. Also, I bought you GAS book. Just start reviewing it on Google Books. Awesome stuff so far.